# Can't open wp-config.php in cPanel

Tags: wordpress

I got this error when trying to open wp-config.php in File Manager (cPanel):
Could not open “/xx/xx/public_html/xxx/wp-config.php” as “xx”: Operation not permitted

Answer (score 0):

This error means that you have no permission to edit the wp-config.php file.

My advice is to contact your hosting provider, as there's nothing we can do for you. Your hosting provider can either override the permissions or explain why it's inaccessible.

You can also try Reinhart Previano's answer if you have the ability to change file permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked out the file permissions? Make sure the `wp-config.php` has both **read** access for both `Group` and `World` from the CPanel's File Manager, though:

[image: screenshot of permissions configuration]

Comment: It is 755. I actually tried 777 too but to no avail.

Comment: Have you checked out the permissions of the parent directories too?

Comment: The parent folder has 0755 permission

Comment: it might show you 755 and still not have those permissions... you should contact your hosting.